# Prove that $g^2=0 \iff W$ has a basis $B = ( w_1, w_2)$ such that $g(w_1) = 0$ and $g(w_2) =λw_1$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $F$ be a field, let $W$ be a 2-dimensional $F$-vector space, and let $g : W → W$. Prove that $g^2=0 \iff W$ has a basis $B = ( w_1, w_2)$ such that
>   $g(w_1) = 0$ and $g(w_2) =λw_1$ for some $λ ∈ F$. What is the representative matrix $_B[g]_B$?

I can show $\Leftarrow $ implication by simply plugging in.

I also think that $_B[g]_B=$ is: \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & \lambda  \\
0 & 0  \end{array}

Correct me if I'm wrong.

Now I'm left to show the $g^2=0 \Rightarrow g(w_2) =λw_1, g(w_1)=0$

I'd appreciate if somebody could explain it to me

Comment: The matrix is correct.

Comment: @Rick Sanchez thanks a lot, I was going to go over this later today :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g$ is identically zero, it is obvious, so assume otherwise. Since $g^2=0$, there has to be some $w_1 \neq0$ in $W$ such that $g(w_1)=0$. (If $g$ is nonzero, there is $x$ such that $g(x)\neq 0$. But $g(g(x))=0$). Extend to a basis $\{w_1,w_2\}$ of $W$. We know $g(w_2)=\lambda w_1+\mu w_2$ for some constants $\lambda$ and $\mu$ in $F$. Applying $g$ to this gives $$0=g(g(w_2))=\lambda g(w_1)+\mu g(w_2)=\mu g(w_2).$$ This implies $\mu=0$ since $g(w_2)$ cannot be zero, or else $g=0$. Hence, $g(w_2)=\lambda w_1.$